# Android React Native local Image source using variable

Tags: android, react-native

When using:

```
<Image source={require('./img/name.png')} />
```

Works great, but how do I use a variable instead?

```
<Image source={require('./img/'+rowData.imageFile+'.png')} />
```

Documentation shows this example https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

```
// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

But that does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources

```
<Image source={{uri: rowData.imageFile}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
```

Just have to put the images under /android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ and specify image dimensions manually.