# React native Image variable in name doesn't work

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I'm trying to load an image that has a variable in it's source, something like this.

```
<View>
  {_.map(this.state.ambiences, (id) => {
    var image = require('../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/' + label + '.png'); // variable label equals "chic" here
    var image2 = require('../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/chic.png');
    return <Image style={styles.pastilleOverlay} source={image} />;
  })}
</View>
```

I get the following error (thrown when trying to set variable image) : Requiring unknown module "../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/chic.png"

If I comment the `var image = ...` line, it works fine with `source={image2}` in the Image tag.

I checked, both strings in the are exactly the same. Any ideas ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230446/android-react-native-local-image-source-using-variable/34231609#34231609

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Workaround

Maybe this [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481) could help you.

> We intentionally don't support dynamically generated image names because it makes it very hard to manage assets over time, just like how you wouldn't want to do 
>   var MyComponent = require('./' + libName + typeOfComponent);
>   or something like that. Dynamic image name generation like this also
>   won't work with the new dynamic asset managing system we're rolling
>   out which let's you add and update assets on the fly with just cmd+R
>   (no more need to add to Xcode and recompile).

### Bundled Images

The images you want to use, need to be bundled "via Xcode asset catalogs or Android drawable folder", as the [documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources). Also you have to specify the dimensions of the images manually.

> Note that this approach provides no safety checks. It's up to you to guarantee that those images are available in the application.

```
<View>
    {_.map(this.state.ambiences, (id) => {
        return <Image style={styles.pastilleOverlay} source={{ uri: '../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/' + label + '.png' }} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />;
    })}
</View>
```

## Alternative

What do you think about using a switch- or if-statement?

```
<View>
    {_.map(this.state.ambiences, (id) => {
        switch (label) {
            case "chic":
                return <Image style={styles.pastilleOverlay} source={require('../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/chic.png')} />;
            case "otherimage":
                return <Image style={styles.pastilleOverlay} source={require('../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/otherimage.png')} />;
            default:
                return <Image style={styles.pastilleOverlay} source={require('../../assets/img/ambiances/icons/default.png')} />;
        }
    })}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be little late, but if you have to have to change image source, update the key for image element. It will treat the re-rendered images as a new component and will require the image correctly.

Simply using image name in the key, did the trick.