# Bug of React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, mobile

I have a problem with React Native FlatList,

```
export default class PoolList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          data: [
            {key: 1, img: './resources/image1.png', txt: 'Text 1'}, 
            {key: 2, img: './resources/image2.png', txt: 'Text 2'}, 
            {key: 3, img: './resources/image3.png', txt: 'Text 3'}
          ]
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.view}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.data}
              renderItem={({item}) => 
                  <View style={styles.flatListItem}>
                    <Image source={require(item.img)} />
                    <Text>{item.txt}</Text>
                  </View>
              }
            />

          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I got a bug when run it

> require() must have a single string literal argument

[image]

But when I change `<Image source={require(item.img)} />` to `<Image source={require('./resources/image1.png')} />`, It works. Can someone explain to me why. I need to make a FlatList with Image dynamic, Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34287046/2266462, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36887177/2266462, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me quite a while to figure out a workaround to this problem. Don't worry, `require() must have a single string literal argument` is a really common problem in the JavaScript community because `require` has a lot of issues with variables being passed in as the string argument.

This is the best workaround I could come up with.

So instead of using a flatlist, I decided to use a map. First off, you need to create `constants` for each of the images you want to dynamically import from a local directory. Then you need to create an `array` of `objects` so each `object` will be one of your `image constants`. Now, iterate through each entry using the `map` and generate your `<Image>` components. Finally, render the variable with all the components you just created.

To view the full code for the solution I wrote, visit the ExpoSnack I created. 
https://snack.expo.io/HyNO-pLQG 
SnackExpo also has an in-browser device simulator included. 
To run this app on your physical device, you can download the Expo app and then scan the QR code provided by the ExpoSnack.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const image1 = require('./resources/image1.png');
const image2 = require('./resources/image2.png');
const image3 = require('./resources/image3.png');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});

var dataArray = [
  {data: image1},
  {data: image2},
  {data: image3},
];

var theReturnData = dataArray.map((item) => (
  <View key={item}>
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      source={item.data}
    />
  </View>
));

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {theReturnData}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help you out! I came across this exact same problem a few months ago but never found a solution. So helping you out with this issue also helped me and hopefully will help a bunch of others who stumble across this post looking for an answer!